# How to create a dynamic device group in Microsoft Intune for devices that have checked in within the last week?

Tags: admin, endpoint, intune

I'm a newbie in Microsoft Intune and I'm trying to create a dynamic device group for devices that have checked in within the last week.

I'm using "lastSyncDateTime" when I configure Dynamic Membership Rules - as example `lastSyncDateTime -ge 2023-08-15` but I have a mistake "Error: Invalid Object type" when I try to create a new group. I tried to use this example `(lastSyncDateTime -ge datetime(2023, 08, 06, 00, 00, 00)) and (lastSyncDateTime -le datetime(2023, 08, 15, 00, 00, 00))`, but there was a mistake "Error: Invalid characters". Sorry I'm confused and I really need help

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to use the API to create these groups rather than the portal. It would be great if you could do this from the portal, because one could create dynamic groups for stale devices, or dynamic groups for active devices.

Anyway, without more information, I cannot help you.